# Properties of custom UITableViewCell are nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to use a custom `UITableViewCell` inside a `UITableViewController`. I've done the following setup:

**Create custom class DPInAppPurchaseCell**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DPBuyButton.h"

@interface DPInAppPurchaseCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet DPBuyButton *buyButton;

@end
```

**Assign custom class in storyboard**

[image]

**Assign cell identifier in storyboard**

[image]

**Register class in viewDidLoad**

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[DPInAppPurchaseCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"InAppPurchaseCell"];
```

**Create cell in UITableViewController**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DPInAppPurchaseCell *cell = (DPInAppPurchaseCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InAppPurchaseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

SKProduct *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.buyButton.titleLabel.text = [product.price stringValue];
cell.descriptionLabel.text = product.localizedDescription;
cell.buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
```

}

**Properties of cell**

[image]

The problem is that the properties of the cell are nil and therefore I can't see it in my 
`UITableViewController`. I've also set a breakpoint to `awakeFromNib:` and `initWithCoder:`
and both methods of my custom cell aren't called at all.

*Edit*

Properties are assigned from Storyboard to .h file.

[image]

Comment: Have you assigned IBOutlets from storyboard/nib to .h file?

Comment: @Mrunal yes they are, please see updated answer.

Comment: is cell nil after DPInAppPurchaseCell *cell = (DPInAppPurchaseCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InAppPurchaseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @MithunMadhav no it's not nil, please see 3rd screenshot.

Comment: on iOS 8 you don't need to call `registerClass:`... not sure if it helps but try to call only `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InAppPurchaseCell"];` instead of `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InAppPurchaseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`... your setup looks correct, weird that `awakeFromNib` isn't called at all

Comment: also you might want to set those cell outlets as weak instead of strong

Comment: @nburk I tried that already but that ended in the same result unfortunately. Also if I do not call registerClass: it crashes.

Comment: remove init with coder ..That may be causing issues

Comment: @MithunMadhav that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I made a demo project and if I keep `registerClass:` properties are nil...removing it fix the problem.

Comment: @GonjiDev Interesting...what deployment target are you using? I'm using iOS 7 and developing with Xcode 6, iOS 8.1 SDK

Comment: I was using deployment target iOS 8.1, XCode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1 SDK. I have also tried with deployment target iOS 7.0 and it works.

Comment: @GonjiDev if I remove it I'm getting the following exception `'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier InAppPurchaseCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Aren't you using prototype cell from storyboard?

Comment: @GonjiDev I'm using prototype cell from storyboard. I'm using a `UITableViewController` with a dynamic prototype cell.